# Como força ação do change do jquery dentro de loop while do php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Boa tarde, estou tentando fazer com que a açao change do jquery funcione dentro de um modal que está dentro de um loop while no php, onde utilizo um select do campo ESTADOS que popular um outro select do campo CIDADES, quando eu acionou o primeiro registro da minha query ele funciona normal e busca as cidades de acordo com o estado que selecionei, isso é quando faço o processo de editar de registro, segue o script:

```
    //FUNCAO  PEGAR CIDADES NATURALIDADE
    $(function (){
        $("#ufs").change(function(){//aqui a função é ativa qdo o usuário sair do campo cpf
            var estados = $("#ufs").val();
            $.post("includeAjax/carregar-cidades.php", {id:estados},
                function(pegar){ $("#cidades").html(pegar); });
        });
    });
```

Mais quando eu edito o segundo registro e abre a modal, e vou acionar o select , ele simplesmente não realizar ação do change ao selecionar os o campo Estados, alguém sabe como fazer para forçar de o change do jquery sobre essa ação? Espero ter explicado direito!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voce pode fazer um `.each` nos options de #ufs e dai para cada val() executar a função

Comment: Pode explicar melhor isso? "loop while no php" acho que isso está criando conflitos em ID's na dom por isso ele não executa o segundo change, ele criou o evento do clique apenas para o primeiro id.

você pode usar uma classe ao invés de usar um id que não gera conflito e para pegar o valor do estado utilize $(this).val()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu tinha comentado você pode tentar pegar o value de cada option do seu select atraves de um `.each` assim :

```
$(function() {
    $("#ufs option").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        // seu codigo ...
    });
});
```

você pode testar ai e ver se funciona para você qualquer coisa da um toque que vejo como melhorar a resposta se isso n for o suficiente para te ajudar